# Regular Expression accepting only 9 digits, no special characters , may have leading zero's only up to 2

Tags: c#, regex

Hi i need a Regular Expression which should accept exactly 9 characters that to only Numbers from 0-9 ,but should not contain all Zeros ,should not contain special characters , may start with zero and leading zero's must be only up to 2.
Regular expression should accept the below pattern

```
123456789
012345678
001234567
```

Right now i have `^[1-9][0-9]{8}$` this regular expression which is accepting 9 digits, no special characters, and should not start with zero.

Comment: *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.* — Which language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lookahead to check *leading zero's must be only up to 2* (and *should not contain all Zeros* in the same step) like

```
^(?!0{3})[0-9]{9}$
```

- `(?!0{3})` discard any number starting with 3 zeros
- `[0-9]{9}`match any other 9 digit number

Answer (score 0):

If RE doesn't have look-ahead then simply build your expression from scratch with all your criteria:

```
^(0[1-9]{8}|00[1-9]{7}|[1-9][0-9]{8})$
```

Again, depending on your engine you may need to escape pipes and some of the brackets :)